# Highlight matching quotes

Tags: syntax-highlighting, delimiters

Is it possible to highlight matching quotes as `show-paren-mode` does with parentheses? The characters I'm looking to highlight are "dumb" quotes, both single (Unicode: apostrophe, U+0027) and double (Unicode: quotation mark, U+0022).

Sometimes I get lost in Fortran format specifiers, like `'("strg1", i2, "strg2", i11)'`. Highlighting matching quotes there would help me tell apart the pieces of the specifier.

I'd prefer not to use `smartparens`. If your solution uses it please provide a set-up that just highlights matching quotes without otherwise altering the pairing or highlighting of matching delimiters.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by matching quotes. Which characters?

Comment: @Drew Both `'` and `"`.

Comment: Put that info in the question, please. So no "curly" quotes - just double-quote (you might mention a programming *"string"*) and apostrophe chars. Giving their Unicode names or code points would be clearest.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

```
(defun show-paren--match-quotes ()
  (let ((ppss (syntax-ppss)))
    ;; In order to distinguish which quote is opening and which is starting,
    ;; check that that point is not within a string (or comment, for that
    ;; matter).  Also ignore escaped quotes.
    (unless (or (nth 8 ppss) (nth 5 ppss))
      (or
       (and (not (bobp))
            (eq 7 (car-safe (syntax-after (1- (point)))))
            (save-excursion
              (let ((end (point))
                    (ppss (syntax-ppss (1- (point)))))
                (when (nth 3 ppss)
                  (let ((beg (nth 8 ppss)))
                    (list beg
                          (1+ beg)
                          (1- end)
                          end))))))
       (and (not (eobp))
            (eq 7 (car-safe (syntax-after (point))))
            (save-excursion
              (let ((beg (point)))
                (condition-case nil
                    (progn
                      (forward-sexp 1)
                      (list beg
                            (1+ beg)
                            (1- (point))
                            (point)))))))))))

(advice-add 'show-paren--default :after-until #'show-paren--match-quotes)
```

Comment: Very nice! But I wanted this because I was getting lost on a Fortran format specifier sort of like `'("blahblah", i2, "blah", i11)'`. In it, `show-paren--match-quotes` only highlights the outer single quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't the `advice-add` rather be `add-function`  on `show-paren-data-function`?

Comment: @npostavs: Indeed.

Comment: @ArchStanton: sorry, I missed that part of your question.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with Fortran to know offhand how to fix that.  What major mode do you use?  `f90-mode`?

Comment: @Stefan Yes. Btw don't worry, that was an edit that I added later.